# How to stop code from executing immediately

Tags: javascript, html

I want my h1 to show "Refresh Page", but every time I load, it automatically executes the code instead and shows results. How can I make this happen? I did some research, but I cant seem to implement it myself, I'm fairly new to programming.

How do I make my page load with "Refresh Page" as a Header?

Html:

```
   <body>
    <h1> Refresh Page </h1>

      <div class="container">
        <div class="container-one">
            <p> Player 1 </p>
            <img class="dice-1" src="Images/dice6.png" alt="Dice-one">
        </div>

        <div class="container-two">
            <p> Player 2</p>
            <img class="dice-2" src="Images/dice6.png" alt="Dice-two">
        </div>
      </div>

     <p class="footer"> © Ylli Ramadani </p>

     <script src="app.js"></script>
      </body>

     // JS

     let randomNumber1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);

     let randomNumber2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);

     const playerOne = (document.getElementsByClassName("dice-1")[0].src =
     "Images/dice" + randomNumber1 + ".png");

     const playerTwo = (document.getElementsByClassName("dice-2")[0].src =
     "Images/dice" + randomNumber2 + ".png");

     // Deciding factor 

     if (playerOne > playerTwo) {
     document.querySelector("h1").innerHTML = " Player 1 wins ";
     } else if (playerOne < playerTwo) {
     document.querySelector("h1").innerHTML = " Player 2 wins ";
     } else {
     document.querySelector("h1").innerHTML = "Draw!!";
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

We can start by adding a header tag to your html. Here I've added a header with the id of "example". Also a button that when clicked will run your game!

```
//HTML
<body>
 <div class="container">
 <h1 id="example">Refresh Page</h1>
   <button id="btn" onclick= "diceGame()">Start</button>
  <div class="container-one">
    <p> Player 1 </p>
    <img class="dice-1" src="Images/dice6.png" alt="Dice-one">
  </div>

  <div class="container-two">
    <p> Player 2</p>
    <img class="dice-2" src="Images/dice6.png" alt="Dice-two">
  </div>
 </div>
 <p class="footer"> © Ylli Ramadani </p>

 <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

You can wrap your javascript into a function and use an event to call it! I've also changed how the header is found with document.getElementById()

```
//JS
function diceGame() {

 let randomNumber1 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);

 let randomNumber2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 + 1);

 const playerOne = (document.getElementsByClassName("dice-1")[0].src =
 "Images/dice" + randomNumber1 + ".png");

 const playerTwo = (document.getElementsByClassName("dice-2")[0].src =
 "Images/dice" + randomNumber2 + ".png");

// Deciding factor 

 if (playerOne > playerTwo) {
  document.getElementById("example").innerHTML = " Player 1 wins ";
 } else if (playerOne < playerTwo) {
  document.getElementById("example").innerHTML = " Player 2 wins ";
 } else {
  document.getElementById("exampel").innerHTML = "Draw!!";
 }
}
```